# HTML form with no action (+ CSP rule no inline javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, content-security-policy

In the past when I've wanted to disable the default action of a form, I've done

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);">
```

We now employ a CSP (Content Security Policy) to disallow inline JavaScript. How can we disable the default form action without the inline js?

Comment: you shouldn't be using inline JS anyway :-) Just add an event listener for the form's `submit` action, and call `preventDefault` on the event

Comment: @RobinZigmond we don't use inline js anymore (haven't for a long time). Is `preventDefault` going to be widely cross-browser acceptable? This is quite an important form on our site

Comment: @KayakinKoder it is supported by all browsers back to IE9.

Comment: yes - back to IE9 according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: Ah, I now remember the problem I was pondering. I thought that a form without an `action` was invalid html. It's not, `action` is an optional attribute. So for anyone wondering about meeting specs/standards, you can simply do `<form name="myForm">`, listen for submit action on `myForm`, and prevent default

Comment: @KayakinKoder - sorry, I only just saw your latest response. You can't disable a form by leaving out the `action` attribute - if it's not given it defaults to submitting the data to the current page.

Answer (score 1):

use jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#form").submit(function (e) {

            //stop submitting the form 
            e.preventDefault();
            return true;

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and welcome to SO. A few things -- first, explain the logic behind your code. What is it doing and why is often more helpful than the code itself. Second, a lot of folks don't use jQuery :) So you may want to say "if you're using jQuery", because a lot of answers in jQuery won't be relevant to some people

Answer (score 1):

You can disallow all form actions from the HTML document by setting `form-action 'none'`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/form-action